# Initialize array of tuples where tuple element requires previous element as ctor arg

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, stdtuple

```
using namespace std;
...
array<tuple<X, Y, Z>, 3> = {make_tuple(X(), Y(get<0>(???)), Z()), ...
```

This obviously doesn't work since there is nothing I can put in the get<>() because the tuple hasn't been constructed yet. Yet, I need to initialize the Y element by type conversion from the X in the same tuple of the given array element. How can I do this? In my situation, Y can only be constructed by this type conversion from X or by a move; there's no default ctor. Moreover, I need a stack-based array, so I cannot use vector instead without writing a stack allocator for vector, which is a huge addition of code for what should be something simple to do.

Comment: I'd probably just push_back them to a vector. How performance sensitive is this code?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I need this structure on the stack (project requirement from our overlords). Surely the language has some way to make this work.

Comment: Hm, `Y(X())` doesn't work?

Comment: Can't you construct `X, Y, Z` separately and then `std::move` them to `make_tuple`?

Comment: jrok, needs to be the previous X, not a new instance.

Comment: @DisplayName `X x; Y y{x}; Z z; array<tuple<X, Y, Z>, 3> = {make_tuple(move(x), move(y), move(z)), ...};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct the X() separately (and please don't use `using namespace std`...)

```
X x;
std::array<std::tuple<X,Y,Z>, 3> a { make_tuple(x, Y(x), Z()), ... };
```

That should work...